# Bootstrap Downdown Menu Button Color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a website with bootstrap and I have problem with a color of a button of dropdown menu. Lets see:

[image: This is how it looks ( it appears when i narrow my webrwoser)]

This is how it looks ( it appears when i narrow my web browser)

[image]

And this is how it looks when I put a mouse on it. All i want is change the color of these three lines (pic 1, u can't see them cause they're white as a button) to black so i could see them on a white background of navbar.

here is the html code

```
<div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/bong.png"></a>
        </div> <!-- end of navbar header-->
```

and css code

```
.navbar {
background-color: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
padding: 1% 0;
}
.navbar-brand {
min-height: 50px;
padding: 0 15px 5px;
}
.navbar-nav li {
padding-right: 20px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li a {
color: black;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li a:hover {
background-color: white;
}
.navbar-header {
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
border-color: white;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
border-color: black;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
background-color: black;
```

Hope that someone will help newbie to fix that problem, thanks ;)

Comment: SO you have to change style for .icon-bar

Comment: but how to do it? and now i think that i would also change border of this button

Answer (score 0):

try to apply hover css on span tag when you put mouse cursor on it. and change your background color when you put mouse on button.

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
        .navbar {
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
        padding: 1% 0;
        }
        .navbar-brand {
        min-height: 50px;
        padding: 0 15px 5px;
        }
        .navbar-nav li {
        padding-right: 20px;
        }
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li a {
        color: black;
        }
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li a:hover {
        background-color: white;
        }
        .navbar-header {
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        }
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
        border-color: white;
        }
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
        border-color: black;
        }
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
        background-color: black;
        }
        span:hover{
            background-color: blue;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span><br/>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span><br/>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0wdX.png"></a>
                </div>

  </body>
</html>
```